# Count elements in array of arrays

Tags: ruby

```
element = [["BLUE", "CAT", "BEAR"], ["BALL", "CHAIR", "BOW"], ["CLOWN", "COLA", "PARROT", "LOVE"]]
```

There are obviously ten elements across the arrays. How do I find the count without flattening the array?

Comment: How duplicates should be counted? `[["A"], ["A"]]` is to return what? 2? Or 1?

Answer (score 7):

With Ruby 2.4,

```
element.sum(&:size) #=> 10
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ary = [["BLUE", "CAT", "BEAR"], ["BALL", "CHAIR", "BOW"], ["CLOWN", "COLA", "PARROT", "LOVE"]]

sum = ary.inject(0) { |tot, e| tot + e.size }

 => 10
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ary.map(&:count).inject(:+)
#⇒ 10
```